Migrating data From old cPanel to new one
I am migrating data from one service provider to another both working on cPanel and want to migrate whole data from old one to new one. I am using remote FTP to migrate data from old cPanel to new cPanel. The error I am getting is Login authentication issue.
I tried doing it manually also but the database and email notification are troughing error. Database having unexpected line error in the database.
So I tried FTP as it is quick and easy but ran into this error.
I checked for the user name and password, it was correct. Any suggestions what else can be done?

FTP Username: nms@domain.com
FTP server: ftp.domain.com
FTP &explicit FTPS port:  21
Pass : *********

